# Unable to train model with XgBoost - PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, data-science, xgboost

I'm attempting to train an XgBoost model with a Spark DataFrame that looks like this :

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
|            features|         TARGET_VAL|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|(122,[0,1,9,10,11...|                0.0|
|(122,[0,1,8,9,11,...| 14.577420000000002|
|[4.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|           65.44524|
|(122,[0,1,8,9,11,...|                0.0|
|(122,[0,1,8,9,10,...|           18.27017|
|(122,[0,1,8,11,12...|                0.0|
|(122,[0,1,8,10,11...|           75.75954|
|(122,[0,1,10,11,1...|           65.32013|
|[1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,...|          171.16563|
|(122,[0,1,8,11,12...|                0.0|
|(122,[0,1,8,9,11,...|                0.0|
|(122,[0,1,8,10,11...|            2.27041|
|(122,[0,1,11,12,2...|                0.0|
|[4.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|           76.08024|
|(122,[0,1,8,9,11,...|                0.0|
|(122,[0,1,8,10,11...|           15.31895|
|(122,[0,1,8,10,11...|          122.56702|
|(122,[0,1,8,10,11...|-30.268179999999997|
|(122,[0,1,8,10,11...|                0.0|
|(122,[0,1,10,11,4...|          136.80025|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I'm using sparkxgb (XgBoost with PySpark) and I'm training the model like this :

```
paramMap = {'eta': 0.1, 'subsample': 0.8}

xgbClassifier = XGBoostClassifier(**paramMap) \
    .setFeaturesCol("features") \
    .setLabelCol("TARGET_VAL")
```

When I'm training the model with :

```
xgboostModel = xgbClassifier.fit(df)
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Classifier found max label value = 23470.00821 but requires integers in range [0, ... 2147483647)
```

So, I cast the TARGET_VAL column to int and upon doing that I'm getting the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Classifier inferred 23471 from label values in column XGBoostClassifier_37d67e9f2233__labelCol, but this exceeded the max numClasses (100) allowed to be inferred from values.  To avoid this error for labels with &gt; 100 classes, specify numClasses explicitly in the metadata; this can be done by applying StringIndexer to the label column.
```

I'm new to XgBoost and Machine Learning. I think TARGET_VAL is the column that the trained model will predict for a test dataset and it's supposed to be a floating point value. So, what am I doing wrong? Do I need to configure the model with different parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that since `TARGET_VAL` is continuous variable column and the `XGBoostClassifier` expects a discrete/categorical variable column. There are way too many classes for the classifer. As you can see in the error max `numClasses` is 100 and I'm sure you have more than 100 numbers.

You are using a classification algorithm for a regression problem.

[Continuous vs Discrete Variables - Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_or_discrete_variable#Continuous_variable)